# xcode C++ : Lexical or Preprocessor issue 'memory' file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, include, std

I'm including a library in a C++ program, which includes memory and other libraries from the std c++ implementation, like so:

```
#include <memory>
```

There is an error happening:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor issue 'memory' file not found
```

This happens the same with all the includes in this file:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
```

I'm wondering what could cause such an issue? Could it be that the compiler is not set somewhere properly in the build settings? If so, any idea where?

Comment: what's the extension of the file you're trying to compile?

Comment: Have you read the questions you can find on SO if you search for "Lexical or Preprocessor issue"?

Comment: You may need to reinstall your compiler or IDE.

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois Fabre, it's being included by an .h header file, so the include memory is inside that header file.

Comment: Follow the chain back up to the translation unit being compiled, Ke. That's what Jean-François Fabre is interested in. If you are trying to compile a .c file including these headers, for example, you're gonna have a bad day.

Comment: Just wanted to say thankyou so much user4581301, this is exactly the answer I needed. If you write this as the answer I'll gladly accept it. I changed the c to cpp file and it works fine now (shouldnt have tried compiling this in c in the first place). Bravo! :)